# Converting signed normalized integer to unsigned normalized integer image format

Tags: opengl

Given I have my texture data in client memory as signed normalized integers.

I want the samples in the shader in the range [0,1]. Can I simply specify:

```
format = GL_RGBA;
internalFormat = GL_RGBA8;
dataType = GL_BYTE;
```

Does this work as expected or does it convert it to [-1,1] and then do the clamp which is certainly not what I want?

Comment: The data would be copied as is, and interpreted based on the type you indicated in the shader pipeline. Casting a signed integer to an unsigned integer doesn't change the data, only how the data is interpreted for mathematical operations.

Comment: When you say the data is in memory as "signed normalized integers", do you mean they are signed byte values from -128 to 127 representing [-1, 1]?  Or something else?

Comment: @NathanReed Exactly what you said. I have numbers from -128 to 127 but want them to represent [0(-128),1(127)].

Comment: @Evan So how are they interpreted? 1. [-1(-128),1(127)] and then clamped to [0,1] or 2. [0(-128),1(127)]

Comment: @Alexander This may be platform dependent. Microsoft compilers will interpret signed values in a twos complement format, as indicated here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/38027. Converting it to an unsigned integer simply removes the twos complement formatting. That 32bit pattern that was previously -128 in signed format, will become "4294967168" when unsigned. So this is something you may want to verify on your specific compiler.